# CakePHP Acessing full User Information

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I am very new to CakePHP and I was just wondering if someone could help me with a couple of things.
I have a User class and an Image class.

In my users_controller.php I have the following functions

```
function beforeFilter(){
    $this->userOb = $this->User->find();
}
function beforeRender(){
    $this->set('userOb', $this->userOb);
}
```

This works fine and I can view the object in my view, with all the correct relations to the Image class.

But doing this overwrites the beforeFilter() and beforeRender() functions in my app_controller.php, so I try and move this functionality to my app_controller.php but I get an error (Undefined property: PagesController::$User)

Also,

```
$this->Auth->user();
```

doesn't seem to have the full object map that

```
$this->User->find();
```

returns.

So, I guess my question is how can I create a variable that is acessable in all my views, i.e it's defined in app_controller.php, that contains the current logged in Users Object and it's relations.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to go back and accept some old answers, you might get a few more responses that wayy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is your parent methods are being overwritten by child methods, simply call the parent method in the child, see below:

```
function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->userOb = $this->User->find();
}
function beforeRender(){
    parent::beforeRender();
    $this->set('userOb', $this->userOb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put your find result in [SessionComponent](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1310/Sessions) so you don't have to perform a query for each request (and set variable in beforeRender). In the view you can access it with SessionHelper. $this->Auth->user(); only have the User record.